# permutation of 2n numbers with a window of n

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, factorial

I am stuck in a question for a while,
Consider 2 list of alphabets,

```
1 2 3 4  
a b c d  
y x w v
```

the questions asks to count the number of ordering/permutations possible,there are also some rules to be followed,
no matter the ordering all positions must add up to **z**, i.e  **a+y = z, b+x=z**

```
  1 2 3 4         1 2 3 4  
  a x w d         a x b d  
  y b c v         y c w v
  accepted         not accepted
```

Now I managed to find out that if all the elements are unique, it follows the double factorial of evens
for this example ,n=4 ans is $384$
I just cant find how to handle duplicates, for example

```
  1 2 3  
  m m a  
  m m y
```

The answer is 6, if all elements were unique it would been 48 , I just cant figure, how to calculate this given the lists
  example, keeping a,y constant. So basically there will be 6*8=48 oderings

```
  a b c   a c b   a w x   a x w  a b w
  y x w   y w x   y c b   y b c  y x c  

  a c x   a c w   a x c
  y w b   y w b   y b w
```

if there are duplicates,

```
  m a   m y   a m  y m
  m y   m a   y m  a m
```

as you can see, if there are duplicates they dont follow the $2^n(n!)$, due to non distinct permutations

Comment: What do you mean by 'all positions must add up to z'? I didn't understand the question.

Comment: @AmitRajaraman basically (a) can be treated as 1 in the alphabets, while (y) is 25, so 1+25 = 26(z)

Comment: same with m(13) +m(13) = z(26), and also z will never appear in the lists

Comment: In your example there are $3$ choices of which column to place the $(a,y)$ and then two choices of which row to put the $a$ in, so $3\dot2=6$ choices in all.

Comment: @saulspatz, I ran a brute force code, it gives 48 combinations https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/nMOY7FTw4W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I hope I’ve now, on the third try, understood the question. Next time, it would be preferable if you’d state the problem in clear general terms rather than merely providing examples and letting us generalize from them.

From what I gather from the examples, it seems that what you’re actually interested in is the number of arrangements of a given multiset of letters in two rows, where each letter can go anywhere in either row, under the condition that the letters in the same column must add up **z**. You seem to be assuming that the given multiset consists of pairs that add up to **z**, so that such an arrangement is in fact possible.

If the multiset contains **m** $2m$ times and $n_k$ copies of each other type of pair for $1\le k\le12$, for a total of $s=m+\sum_kn_k$ columns, then the number of admissible arrangements is

$$
\frac{s!}{m!\prod_kn_k!}2^{s-m}\;.
$$

There are $s!$ permutations of the pairs, but for each type of pair we need to divide by the number of permutations among that type, since the result is invariant under them. And we have to multiply by a factor $2$ for each pair that’s not **mm**, since for each such pair there’s an independent binary choice which of the two letters to put in the top row.

Comment: This ignores the fact that that the elements in the top and bottom row can be inverted.  We have $n!\cdot2^n=(2n)!!$ as the OP says.

Comment: @saulspatz: Ah, thanks, I didn't look at the examples carefully enough and misunderstood the question.

Comment: I have added more example, I hope it makes my question more clear, thanks

Comment: @Julkar9: OK, I hope I've now understood the question correctly. Sorry about the wrong initial answer.

Comment: I have managed to get upto that, but my problem arises due to duplicates, as I mentioned using the (m) example.

Comment: @Julkar9: OK, then I still haven't understood the question. I think you need to state more clearly what you're trying to count. Can any letter go anywhere as long as the pairs add up to **z**? Then the count would trivially be $25^n$, so that's probably not what you mean. But then what are the other conditions other than the pairs adding up to **z**?

Comment: ok I will add another example using duplicates

Comment: I have added a small example, here is a program as well https://ide.geeksforgeeks.org/hR0tcEbPxm, which works upto n=7

Comment: @Julkar9: I hope that my understanding is correct now; I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thank you very much and my apologies for not framing a general question